# Is there any way to know if connected device is a specific one?

Tags: c#

I want to let just specific DOK device something- 
is there way to know that the specific DOK is connected to my machine??-
 like MAC address or something else?- and if so- how do I do it through the code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that USB drives (i.e., thumb drives or "disk on key" devices) do not have a unique identifier. They do have an "identifier" of sorts but it may change when the drive is formatted.

You can use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) to read [`Win32_LogicalDisk.VolumeSerialNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but keep in mind that it doesn't uniquely identify a physical device.